# Once demoted to a lower arena, then promoted back, will the arena offer return?

Tags: clash-royale

So I’m in arena 10, but I forgot to buy the arena offer. If I demoted myself to arena 9 then back to 10, will the offer come back up?

Answer (score 1):

The *Arena pack* stays for 2 days once you reach for the first time an arena.

Then, if you don't buy it, it will be shown every week.

Answer (score 0):

You can't demote to and fro arenas anymore, but still I will answer your quesion.
If you get demoted, the offer will stay there for a period, for your reward in entering a new arena, even you got demoted. The offer will still be available for purchase, until the period of time ends or you get promoted.